# About pandas datareader

Tags: python, pandas

When I try to import pandas datareader, it throws me an error.

I tried following pattern because some one said it should be underscore `pandas_datareader` when you import it.

Please help.

**Package**

```
PS C:\Users\cris\Anaconda3> conda list | Select-String "pandas-datareader"

pandas-datareader         0.4.0                    py36_0


PS C:\Users\cris\Anaconda3>
```

**Python**

> ```
> >>> import pandas_datareader.data as web
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
> >>>
> >>> import pandas-datareader.data as web
>   File "<stdin>", line 1
>     import pandas-datareader.data as web
>                  ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> >>>
> >>> import pandas-datareader-0.4.0.data as web
>   File "<stdin>", line 1
>     import pandas-datareader-0.4.0.data as web
>                  ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> >>>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

See this: 
https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The correct syntax is:

```
import pandas_datareader
```

common convention is to import it as 'pdr' so a lot of code you read on the web will say this:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

if you just want the web module, use this:

```
from pandas_datareader import wb
```

Comment: I was able to resolve.
But it works on jupyter notebook.
still doesn't work on terminal...

Is it like that?

Comment: what are you using for your terminal? Works fine for me in spyder... You're using a standard Anaconda installation?

Comment: Ah,, I have been using Windows command prompt,,,
That is not recommended?

Comment: there's a lot better coding environments than that. Anaconda comes with a combined coding / code execution environment called Spyder, or you can use IDLE which is the default with Python. With regards to your use of the windows command prompt, perhaps some libraries aren't set in the PATH properly which is what is causing the problem. Try one of the other development environments or through the anaconda prompt and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas_datareader as web

web.__version__
```

Output:

```
'0.4.0'

df = web.DataReader('MSFT','google')
df.head()
```

Output:

```
             Open   High    Low  Close    Volume
Date                                            
2010-01-04  30.62  31.10  30.59  30.95  38414185
2010-01-05  30.85  31.10  30.64  30.96  49758862
2010-01-06  30.88  31.08  30.52  30.77  58182332
2010-01-07  30.63  30.70  30.19  30.45  50564285
2010-01-08  30.28  30.88  30.24  30.66  51201289
```

Comment: Thank you for replying.
I tried but still having error...

>>> import pandas_datareader as web
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'

Comment: I think you need to 'pip install pandas-datareader' in the appropriate environment on you computer.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I was able to resolve.
Problem was...i installed it with 'conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda pandas-datareader'

Because I use Anaconda..
Package installation by  'conda' can not get full function something like that?  
You don't use anaconda?